# Datatable insert trigger

Tags: vb.net, ado

I would like to implement sql insert trigger on dataset table.

My app has two dataset tables:

`-- Table: Artikli --
IDB - int,autoincrement
Sifra - int, primary key
Naziv - string
Cena - double
PS - string`

`-- Table: PodArtikli --
IDB - int,autoincrement,primary key
Sifra - int
Naziv - string
Cena - double
Kolicina - int
Ukupno - computed column (Cena*Kolicina)
Pakovanje - double
Jed.Mere - string
PLU - string, unique
Cena_Po_Meri - computed column (1000/Pakovanje * Cena)`

These tables are related through foreign key constraint where parent table is `Artikli` and child table is `PodArtikli` on column `Sifra`.
I would like, when a new row is added into `Artikli`, to automatically add new row in the `PodArtikli` table with `Sifra,Naziv`, and `Cena` values from added row in `Artikli` table.

The data from dataset tables is displayed in DataGridView.
On the click event of button `btnizmene` I have the following code:

```
Dim novirow As DataRow = dspetrovac.Artikli.NewRow
novirow("Sifra") = grdpodaci.Item(1, grdpodaci.CurrentRow.Index).Value
novirow("Naziv") = grdpodaci.Item(2, grdpodaci.CurrentRow.Index).Value
novirow("Cena") = grdpodaci.Item(3, grdpodaci.CurrentRow.Index).Value
novirow("PS") = grdpodaci.Item(4, grdpodaci.CurrentRow.Index).Value
```

Comment: Triggers are usually implementing in the database, although the DataTable does have some events.  If the DGV is bound to a datasource, you dont have to shuttle data manually into a newRow item

Comment: I also tried TableNewRow event but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write a trigger in .NET `DataTable` but you can implement something similar using `DataTable` events. For example, you can take `RowChanging` event and take changing row, see if row is added and then use data from that row to insert new row into child table

```
Private Sub Row_Changing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataRowChangeEventArgs)
    If e.Action = DataRowAction.Add Then 
        Dim newChild as DataRow = childTable.NewRow()
        ' Get new row fr here and insert values 
        newChild("field") = e.Row("field")
        . . . . . . . 
        childTable.Rows.Add(newChild)
    End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thnx for the idea. Instead of Row_Changing i used Row_Changed because in Row_Changing event row is not yet actually added and exception InvalidConstraintException is raised saying that row with column 'Sifra' value in child table does not exist in parent table. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Gruja82 This is fine. This is exactly what my attempt was - guide you into right direction. `rowchanged` or `rowChanging` - are just technicality, which you need to workout based on your software construction and  execution flow. Enjoy.